# Clear Fields after Form submission(google form web app)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-forms

Here is my code,

```
 <iframe name="hiddenFrame" class="hide"></iframe>
 <form name="myForm" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzmDHjN1jyFdZTvH2f2GLKp1pyLmNAj-R_yjAGoiw/exec" method="post" class="wow fadeInUp" id="contact-form" role="form" data-wow-delay="0.8s" target="hiddenFrame">
```

My question,
how can I clear fields after click the submit button when I use this google docs. `reset()` works but passed data was empty. I want pass data successful and clear field. How can I do that?

Comment: Show the `submit` function code

Comment: <button type="submit"  class="form-control" id="cf-submit" name="submit" >Send Message</button>

Comment: Would like to see the function which is used to reset

Comment: <script>
function reset1()
{
 document.getElementById('cf-submit').reset();
}


</script>

Comment: are u able to console the value of form before reset it?

Comment: no i cant do that also.

Comment: Post your relevant code in the question!